# Render a react app in a non react web page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I was wondering if its possible to render an entire react app in a non react web page. I tried many links where it suggested code snippets as follows which shows to render just a component,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@latest/dist/react.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@latest/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
      </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root">
        <h1>POC</h1>


    </body>
    <script type="text/babel">
        class Application extends React.Component {
            render() {
                //debugger             
                console.log('hi there')
                return (
                    <div>
                        <h1>hello world</h1>
                    </div>
                );
            }
        }

        ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('root'));
    </script>
</html>
```

But i want to know is its possible to have my react app in the same path like,

```
- htdocs
    - plainhtmljswebapp.html
    - react-app-folder
        - index.html
        - main.js
        - src
            - components
            - actions
            - reducers
        - package.json
        - webpack.config.js
```

as my web app and load/ import it and pass it some values as props if its possible. I have never done such integration before and any help on its feasibility/ approach would be much appreciated.

Thanks alot

Comment: why can't you just iframe the react part?

Comment: @A.Lau the reason i need to pass it some values as props to the react app from the web app..to my knowledge this is not possible with iframes right

Comment: I don't see why not.  `ReactDOM.render` will render any component to a div, so you could wrap it in a function to pass it some custom props import you bundle like normal and call the function in a `script` tag.

Comment: @MichaelPeyper is it possible for that application use the redux state?

Comment: Again, I don't see why not.  If i get some time, I'll knock together a quick example for you an post an answer.

Comment: @HasithaShan done.  I hope I understood what you were looking for well enough.  Leave comments if I have missed an integral part of the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*See comments on question for more context on this answer*

---

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/bundle.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content1">
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            mount("content1", "testing")
        </script>

        <div id="content2">
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            mount("content2", "more testing")
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

#### index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { App } from './app'

window.mount = function(id, customText) {
    const store = createStore((state = {}) => state)
    render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <App text={customText} />
        </Provider>, 
        document.getElementById(id)
    )
}
```

---

#### app.js

```
import React from 'react'

export const App = ({ text }) => {
    return (
        <div>{text}</div>
    )
}
```

---

This only has redux integration in so far as it creates a store and wraps the app in a `Provider`, but I can't see any reason why it wont work like normal from there.

I tested this using webpack to bundle and webpack-dev-server to serve.

Comment: This is a great solution. I understand what you have done there. you are binding the `mount` function to `window` with `render` in it so that is can be invoked in the html.. thanks alot :)

Comment: Question
I'm having trouble getting this work in my application. 
what would happen if invoke mount function twice..
mount("content1", "testing")
mount("content1", "xx testing") -> ??
asume mount function is in an ajax response...based on user click..

Comment: I haven't tested it but `render` can be delayed and should replace the content in the div on subsequent calls, i.e. the second `mount` call should override the first. Note, in the example shown, this would create a new tee redux store so if you wanted the state to persist, some changes would be needed (e.g. cache the store by div `id`).